# How to use NSObject subclass?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

So I've created a subclass of NSObject called `Query`

```
@interface Query : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *weight;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *bodyFat;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *activityLevel;

@end
```

Is this correct for setting the object's property?

In VC1:

```
BodyFatViewController *aViewController = [[BodyFatViewController alloc]init];
aViewController.query = self.query;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
```

In VC2:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    Query *anQuery = [[Query alloc]init];
    anQuery.bodyFat = [self.bodyFatArray objectAtIndex:row];
    anQuery.weight = self.query.weight;
    self.query = anQuery;
}
```

Comment: I assume that your init method is coded according to the template, with a call to super.init and an assignment of self, right?

Comment: I have not added an init method for the `Query` object. The `init` method for either VC doesn't do anything other than call super init.

Comment: You should be good then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly natural to share an object between two VCs:

in VC1:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Query *query;
@synthesize query=_query;

// init it
self.query = [[Query alloc] init];
self.query.weight = [NSNumber numberWithInt:150];

// when it's time to present VC2:
BodyFatViewController *aViewController = [[BodyFatViewController alloc]init];
aViewController.query = self.query;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
```

and then in VC2:

```
// this is in the public interface in VC2.h
//
@property (strong, nonatomic) Query *query;
```

**Don't alloc/init it in VC2.  VC1 did that!!**  But feel free to set or overwrite values...

```
self.query.bodyFat = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5];
```

Comment: Ok perfect, so I don't have to aloc/init a new query in the 2nd VC? Thats done automatically

Comment: Yep. It's done by vc1.  Vc2 gets a handle to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new query simply use the property:

```
self.query.bodyFat = [self.bodyFatArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: In the previous VC, I set one property of the query object though (weight), and now I want to set the bodyFat.  How can I do that?  I have `BodyFatViewController *aViewController = [[BodyFatViewController alloc]init];
 aViewController.query = self.query;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:aViewController animated:YES];`

Comment: `self.query.bodyFat = [self.bodyFatArray objectAtIndex:row];`

Comment: No, there 2 separate vcs.  In VC1, I set the weight property, then pass the object to VC2, then in VC2, I set the bodyFat property, then pass object to VC3, etc.

Comment: In every VC do a `@property Query* query`. when you create a VC you do the `VC* vc = [[VC alloc] init]; vc.query=self.query` before do the push and in every delegate of the pickerView `self.query.property=pickerView.row`. I have understand well your question?

Comment: I updated the question.  I basically want to use one object between a few VCs.  I set different properties in each VC because that is how the UI is.

Comment: I update the response. Don't create a new query in VC2 use the one you have did.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct.

`self.query = newQueryObject`

or

`myBodyFatViewController.query = newQueryObject`

Both work.